# Grocery Store for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been at this for a few days. I need to be able to return items in the cartList that the user has bought before. I don't know what to do!

```
items = [('diapers', 10.00), ('peanuts', 5.00), ('butter', 6.25), ('cheese', 
3.00), ('milk', 3.5), ('yogurt', 1.99), ('eggs', 4.5), ('bread', 4), 
('shrimp', 2.5), ('coffee', 1.5)]

money = 50
ask = ('buy', 'return', 'quit')
cartList = []

while ask != 'quit':

    print("""

        Diapers ....10.00
        Peanuts ....5.00
        Butter .....6.25
        Cheese .....3.00
        Milk .......3.50
        Yogurt .....1.99
        Eggs .......4.50
        Bread ......4.00
        Shrimp .....2.50
        Coffee .....1.50
        """)

     ask = input('Do you want to buy, return or quit?\n').lower()

     if ask == 'buy':
         item = input('\nWhat item do you need?\n').lower()

         for i in items:
             if item == i[0]:
                 print(item, 'is $', i[1])
                 ques = input('\nDo you want to buy this item? 
                 [Y:N]\n').lower()

             if i[1] > money:
                 print('You do not have enough money for this item :(\n')
                 break

             if ques == 'n':
                 print('Sorry that you do not want that item :(')
                 break

             if ques == 'y':
                 money = money - i[1]
                 print('\nYou now have $', money)
                 cartList.insert(0, item)

                 print('You have these items in your cart:\n', cartList, 
                 '\n')

             else:
                print('You entered an incorrect value :(')

     if ask == 'return':
         ret = input('What item do you want to return?\n')

         for i in cartList:
             if ret == i[0]:
                 print(i[0], '$', i[1])
                 quest = input('Do you want to return this item? 
 [Y:N]]\n').lower()

         else:
             print('This item is not in your cart!\n')



 print('\nThank you for shopping with us!')
```

Where there is the ask = return, I need the user to be able to return the item they have bought. I tried a few to many attempts to try to get the user to be able to return the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the part where you insert your item into the cartList. You only insert the item, not the money with it. So in the return part, it must be:

```
if ask == 'return':
    ret = input('What item do you want to return?\n')
    for i in cartList:
        if ret==i:
        ...
```

Or if you want to insert both the item and money into cartList, it should be:

```
...
if ques == 'y':
    money = money - i[1]
    print('\nYou now have $', money)
    cartList.insert((item,i[1]),0)
...
```

Also, you haven't build the if-else part for **quest(Y/N)**
If the user input is Y, you might want to use the **del** method to delete that element from cartList

Answer (score 0):

There are few minor indentation errors in your code apart from the logic which you are missing like removing the return item from your cartList.
Try printing all the items right after you get into,

```
if ask=='return':
     print cartList
```

after you've asked customer to return the item, try python's remove method to return the item from the list.

```
for i in cartList:
   cartList.remove(i)
```